# Getting parse exception

Tags: java, xml, spring, aop

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

<!-- <context:annotation-config/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

 -->
 <bean name="triangle" class="springaop.service.model.Triangle">
 <property name="name" value="triagnle name"/>
 </bean>
  <bean name="circle" class="springaop.service.model.Circle">
 <property name="name" value="cirlce name"/>
 </bean>
  <bean name="shapeservice" class="springaop.service.model.Shapeservice" autowire="byname"/>

 </bean>
```

This is my XML file.

```
package springaop;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import springaop.service.Shapeservice;

public class Aopmain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

   ApplicationContext  ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring1.xml");

    Shapeservice shapeservice = ctx.getBean("shapeservice",Shapeservice.class);
    System.out.println(shapeservice.getCircle().getName());
    }

}
```

This is my main app...please help solving this...

```
Mar 23, 2016 9:31:47 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@b1a58a3: startup date [Wed Mar 23 09:31:47 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 23, 2016 9:31:48 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring1.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 20 in XML document from class path resource [spring1.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 93; cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'byname' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[default, no, byName, byType, constructor, autodetect]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at springaop.Aopmain.main(Aopmain.java:12)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 93; cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'byname' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[default, no, byName, byType, constructor, autodetect]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:458)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3237)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processOneAttribute(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2832)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2769)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2056)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:766)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 14 more
```

Im using Spring 4 and
aspectj1.8/lib/aspectjrt.jar/aspectj1.8/lib/aspectjweaver.jar/aopalliance-alpha1.jar/cglib-3.2.1.jar/asm-4.1/lib/asm-4.1.jar

Comment: You didn't accept my answer. :p

Comment: Sorry it was long time ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems in your code.
You haven't ended the starting 'beans' tag in your spring configuration file, rather you have kept 'bean' end-tag there instead of 'beans' end-tag.

and another one is: "Autowiring by name" requires keyWord 'byName' & not 'byname'. Replace 'byname' with 'byName'.

third one is just spelling mistake:
In your spring configuration file, you have a bean namely 'triangle' whose property 'name' has the value 'triagnle name', which is the spelling mistake. Maybe it may not affect, but it may affect you in future adjustments.
You can change it back to "triangle name".

Answer (score 1):

In this bean definition:

```
<bean name="shapeservice" class="springaop.service.model.Shapeservice" autowire="byname"/>
```

change `byname` to `byName`. Correct definition should be:

```
<bean name="shapeservice" class="springaop.service.model.Shapeservice" autowire="byName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the root tag`<beans>` does not have matching end tag `</beans>`. You have `</bean>` as the ending tag in your `xml`, change it to `</beans>` and see that should work.

`<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
...
</beans>` --> note the matching tag in your XML.